# Differences between MATLAB and Numpy/Scipy FFT

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, fft

**EDIT**:
As it turns out this is still a question of floating point rounding error like others. The asymmetry in fft vs ifft absolute error comes from the difference in the magnitudes of the numbers (1e10 vs 1e8).

---

So there are many questions about the differences between Numpy/Scipy and MATLAB FFT's; however, most of these come down to floating point rounding errors and the fact that MATLAB will make elements on the order of 1e-15 into true 0's which is not what I'm after.

I am seeing a totally different issue where for identical inputs the Numpy/Scipy FFT's produce differences on the order of 1e-6 from MATLAB. At the same time for identical inputs the Numpy/Scipy IFFT's produce differences on the order or 1e-9. My data is a complex 1D vector of length 2^14 with the zero point in the middle of the array (If you know how to share this let me know). As such for both languages I am calling fftshift before and after the fft (ifft) operation.

My question is where is this difference coming from and, more importantly, why is it asymmetric with the fft and ifft? I can live with a small difference but 1e-6 is large when it accumulates over a large number of fft's.

The functional form of the fft (I'm not doing anything else to it) for either language is:

```
def myfft
    return fftshift(fft(fftshift(myData)))
def myifft
    return fftshift(ifft(fftshift(myData)))
```

I have the data saved in a .mat file and load it with scipy.io.loadmat into python. The data is a (2**14,) numpy array

The fft differences are calculated and plotted with

```
myData = loadmat('mydata.mat',squeeze_me=True)
plt.figure(1)
py = myfft(myData['fft_IN'])
mat = myData['fft_OUT']
plt.plot(py.real-mat.real)
plt.plot(py.imag-mat.imag)
plt.title('FFT Difference')
plt.legend(['real','imaginary'],loc=3)
plt.savefig('fft_diff')
```

[image: FFT Difference (python-matlab)]

and the ifft differences are calculated with

```
myData = loadmat('mydata.mat',squeeze_me=True)
plt.figure(1)
py = myifft(myData['ifft_IN'])
mat = myData['ifft_OUT']
plt.plot(py.real-mat.real)
plt.plot(py.imag-mat.imag)
plt.title('FFT Difference')
plt.legend(['real','imaginary'],loc=3)
plt.savefig('fft_diff')
```

[image: IFFT Difference (python-matlab)]

Versions:
Python:3.7
MATLAB:R2019a
Scipy:1.4.1
Numpy:1.18.5

Comment: The absolute differences are irrelevant, what matters is the relative differences. A difference of 1e-16 in a value of 1 is the same as a difference of 1e-6 on a value of 1e10. Considering the length of your data, it is likely that the FFT produces such large values. In short, your results still differ only by floating-point rounding errors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo If you want to make this an answer I will accept it. You comment made me go back and look at the magnitude of the data that I was using. Into the fft function I am feeding things on the order of 1e10 and into the ifft I am feeding 1e8. So it makes sense I am getting a difference in absolute error but not relative error.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer yourself. One more thing: the input to `fft`  must be prepared with `ifftshift`. If the data length is odd this makes a difference. `fftshift` shifts the origin from the left to the middle, `ifftshift` shifts it back from the middle to the left.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out this is still a question of floating point rounding error like all the other MATLAB vs numpy fft questions.

For my data the output of the fft function has numbers on the order of 1e10. This means that a precision of around 1e-16 on a float of this size is an absolute error less than or equal to 1e-6. The asymmetry in fft vs ifft absolute error comes from the output of the ifft being around 1e8. As such, this absolute error would then be less than or equal to 1e-8 which is exactly what we see.

Credit for this goes to @CrisLuengo who also helpfully pointed out that the ordering of fftshift and ifftshift for proper handing of odd length arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to come up with a better workable example to show what you're after (also I don't have MATLAB, just Octave, and likely many others). I ran a quick code of fft and back with no issues. Be aware, generally DFTs (FFTs) are extremely nuanced to work with. You need to consider sampling, windowing, etc. very carefully.

Also, why the comparison to MATLAB to begin with, are you trusting it more, or just want to learn more about why one package produces an answer vs another? MATLAB uses fftw under the hood, which is very well tested and documented, but it doesn't mean that all the above nuances aren't coming into play in a different way.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fft = np.fft.fft
ifft = np.fft.ifft
def myfft(myData):
    return fft(myData)
def myifft(myData):
    return ifft(myData)

myData = np.exp(-np.linspace(-1, 1, 256)**2 / (2 * .25**2))
plt.figure(1)
fft_python = myifft(myfft(myData))
plt.plot(myData - fft_python.real)
plt.plot(fft_python.imag)
plt.title('FFT Difference')
plt.legend(['real','imaginary'],loc=3)
plt.savefig('fft_diff')
```

Comment: I am trusting MATLAB data because it has been reproduced by others in Octave, MATLABm, and Mathematica (academia). If you are curious to see what it looks like with my data, I hosted it at: https://gofile.io/d/S10fcl. The issue here is again just floating point rounding error but it's more nuanced that previous questions. My data into fft is ~1e10 and ifft is ~1e8. So the difference in absolute error is expected. You will have to add fftshifts to your fft functions to get it exactly.